# seeking explanation for timer tutorial

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Hi everyone I am new to JavaScript and was watching some tutorials on the stopwatch in javascript I manage to understand most of the code but still have some questions. I was wondering can someone help explain the purpose of the interval being null. and how did this code work? how did it prevent the function starts

```js
// Global variables
const time_el = document.querySelector('.watch .time');
const start_btn = document.getElementById('start');
const stop_btn = document.getElementById("stop");
const reset_btn = document.getElementById("reset");

let seconds = 0;
let interval = null;

// Event listeners
start_btn.addEventListener('click', start);
stop_btn.addEventListener("click", stop);
reset_btn.addEventListener("click", reset);

// Update the timer
function timer() {
  seconds++;

  // Format our time
  let hrs = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
  let mins = Math.floor((seconds - (hrs * 3600)) / 60);
  let secs = seconds % 60;

  if (secs < 10) secs = '0' + secs;
  if (mins < 10) mins = "0" + mins;
  if (hrs < 10) hrs = "0" + hrs;

  time_el.innerText = `${hrs}:${mins}:${secs}`;
}

function start() {
  if (interval) {
    return
  }

  interval = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
}

function reset() {
  stop();
  seconds = 0;
  time_el.innerText = '00:00:00';
}
```

```html
<div class="watch">
  <div class="time"></div>
</div>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

from running again when I clicked more than once?

```js
function start () {
    if (interval) {
        return
    }

    interval = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
```

I pasted the whole JS code to give a better context

Comment: In JS `null` (among some other values) is [`falsey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).  Look at `if` condition inside `start()` function.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! so if (interval) always needs to be true before it can continue down right ?

Answer (score 1):

1. In javascript `null` evaluates to `false` (falsy values): [js-falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), there are also values that evaluate to `true` (truthy values): [js-truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), so they initialize the variable `interval` to `null` so the code knows whether to start the timer, if it doesn't evaluate to `false` (falsy) the timer has been started and `setInterval` has been called, so it `returns` immediately on another click of the start button.
2. `setInterval` returns an Interval ID which is a unique identifier: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), this is what is stored in `interval` on initial start button click, so on subsequent clicks, the variable `interval` evaluates to `true` (truthy).
3. Added a code snippet to demonstrate what I tried to describe in points 1 and 2.

```js
let interval = null;

//Check to see if interval evaluates to false(falsy)
if(!interval){
  console.log("interval evaluated to false(falsy)");
}

//set interval to the ID of call to setInterval()
interval = setInterval(() => { 
    console.log("setInterval() called and interval set to my ID");
  }, 1000000);

//Check to see if interval evaluates to true(truthy)  
if(interval){
   console.log("setInterval ID: " + interval);
   console.log("interval evaluated to true(truthy)");
}
```

Comment: 1.oh so interval was null at the start which also equate to a false 
2. once i use setinterval the interval got an "ID" which also equate to a true

is that correct? and using the if(interval) is basically asking if interval is true it would run ?

Comment: @trox Exactly. That is why on subsequent clicks of the start button, it returns instead of executing the piece of code where it calls `setInterval`

Comment: @trox `if(interval)` is checking to see if `interval` evaluates to `true`, if it's truthy it returns and doesn't execute the code where it calls `setInterval`, the first time the button is clicked `interval` is falsy, so it doesn't enter the if condition and `return` and instead calls `setInterval` and sets `interval` to the ID of `setInterval`